# Display the users that have not yet created projects this month in specific city

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query that display the clients that haven't created a project this month.

```
SELECT u.userName
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT userName FROM projects) u
LEFT JOIN projects p
    ON u.userName = p.userName AND
       MONTH(p.date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) AND
       YEAR(p.date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
WHERE
    p.userName IS NULL
```

Live exemple : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/53de526/5

Now I want to filter them by city. I tried different things but none of them are working.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Your requirement does not make much sense, because the city is associated with a project, and your query is actually asking for users who, in the current month, have _no_ projects associated with them.  Therefore, the users which your query returns also have no cities associated with them.  Maybe you should change your table design.

Answer (score 1):

From your question and example, I came up with this... Give this a try and see if that what you want.

```
SELECT u.userName, u.city
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT userName, city FROM projects) u
LEFT JOIN projects p
    ON u.userName = p.userName AND
       MONTH(p.date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) AND
       YEAR(p.date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())      
WHERE
    p.userName IS NULL
    and u.city = 'Paris'
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve this. Here is one:

```
SELECT
  p.*
FROM
  projects AS p
  INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      userName
      ,MAX(date) AS max_date
    FROM 
      projects p
    GROUP BY
        userName
    HAVING
      max_date < DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, '%Y-%m-01')
  ) AS mp
  ON p.userName = mp.userName AND p.date = mp.max_date
WHERE
  p.city = 'Bordeaux'
```

This finds the max value of `date`, filters on those that do not occur in the current month, and joins the results back to the original table where we then filter on `city`. I show `'Bordeaux'` as an example, but you can input any value(s) you want.

Comment: @JonathanJHH, you're welcome. Please mark this as the selected answer if it does solve your problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT u.userName, u.city
        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM projects) u
        LEFT JOIN projects p
            ON u.userName = p.userName AND
               MONTH(p.date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) AND
               YEAR(p.date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())      
        WHERE
            p.userName IS NULL AND u.city='Paris'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: `DISTINCT *` is an oxymoron within the context of a properly normalised database.

Answer (score 0):

Specification is a bit unclear.

We could generate (username,city) pairs where there isn't a matching project in the current month. If we don't have a source for the list of city values, we can get it from the projects table, just like we got a list of username:

```
SELECT u.username
     , c.city
  FROM ( SELECT pu.username
           FROM projects pu
          GROUP
             BY pu.username
       ) u
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT pc.city
           FROM projects pc
          GROUP
             BY pc.city
       ) c
    -- anti-join    
  LEFT
  JOIN projects p
    ON p.username = u.username
   AND p.city     = c.city
   AND p.date     >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') + INTERVAL 0 MONTH
   AND p.date     <  DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
 WHERE p.username IS NULL
 ORDER
    BY u.username
     , c.city
```

If we want to "filter", we can add to the `WHERE` clause ...

```
 WHERE p.username IS NULL
   AND c.city = 'Paris'
```

Or we could have just incorporated that condition into the inline view `c`

```
SELECT u.username
     , c.city
  FROM ( SELECT pu.username
           FROM projects pu
          GROUP
             BY pu.username
       ) u
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT pc.city
           FROM projects pc
          WHERE pc.city = 'Paris'
          GROUP
             BY pc.city
       ) c
    -- anti-join    
  LEFT
  JOIN projects p
    ON p.username = u.username
   AND p.city     = c.city
   AND p.date     >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') + INTERVAL 0 MONTH
   AND p.date     <  DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
 WHERE p.username IS NULL
 ORDER
    BY u.username
     , c.city
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use aggregation:

```
select p.username
from projects p
group by p.username
having sum( month(p.date) = month(CURRENT_DATE()) and
            year(p.date) = year(CURRENT_DATE()) and
          ) = 0;
```

You mention the city.  It appears that your data is denormlized, and `city` is for the *user* not the *project*.  If so, just put it in the `select` and `group by`:

```
select p.username, p.city
from projects p
group by p.username, p.city
having sum( month(p.date) = month(CURRENT_DATE()) and
            year(p.date) = year(CURRENT_DATE()) and
          ) = 0;
```

Normally, you would have a separate table of users.  The above will obviously only return users that have a project.  With a separate table, though, you can get users with *no* projects as well.  For this, I would use `not exists`:

```
select u.*
from users u
where not exists (select 1
                  from projects p
                  where month(p.date) = month(CURRENT_DATE()) and
                        year(p.date) = year(CURRENT_DATE())
                 );
```

And you would get the city along with other information.